# go get package in a subdirectory of a github repo

Tags: github, go

If you have a go-only repo (let's say it's https://github.com/foo/bar), you can put your code right at the root level, and have others import using the following command:

```
go get -u github.com/foo/bar
```

Directories and subdirectories therein would be recognized as packages.

But suppose you are creating a multi-language repo on github (e.g. one that has java code, go code, javascript code, etc.). And you want to make your go code available for others to use. Usually putting the go code right at the root level would be a no-no from the code organization standpoint. What might be more common may be

```
(root)
  |-- src
       |-- main
            |-- go
            |-- java
            |-- javascript
            |-- proto
```

The root level of your go code is now at https://github.com/foo/bar/src/main/go. But you can no longer use the previous `go get` command as it would look at the top level. You don't really want to use `go get -u github.com/foo/bar/src/main/go` either as all those would now become part of the package names which is real yucky.

Question is, is there a way to specify an exact URL so that you can separate the package names and the URL? In other words, I'm looking for something like

```
go get -u github.com/foo/bar https://github.com/foo/bar/src/main/go
```

(of course the package names should match those that are actually in the source, otherwise it won't compile).

I looked at the go documentation, but it isn't clear to me whether this is doable.

Comment: The import path is the path to the package code. That is the convention the go tool follows.

Comment: Consider making the Go package (and any other stand-alone parts) their own project and repo. It will avoid many problems. Make another repo to pull them all together, if necessary, with [submodules](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/01/11/us/11kinnard.html). Or even better, use a packaging tool to bring the pieces together.

Comment: There is no reason that libraries for multiple languages should all be in the same repo. They should each be in their own repositories.

Comment: I agree normally you want to have a repo for each language. In this specific case, the repo is primarily a protobuf-based API. Obviously we have the proto files for the message definitions. And we have code-gen'ed source for the languages we support. If we support, let's say, N languages, then we would need to create N+1 repos (one for the proto files, N for all the languages). Thus the question on how we can organize this into a single repo still.

Comment: The fact that the path in the repo and the import path are the same is strictly a convention that the tools follow. Being able to `go get` from github is a convenience, and if you want that convenience you have to follow the convention. You can change that more or less transparently by inserting an intermediary server like gopkg.in, but that doesn't change how import paths work. You are free to move the code anywhere you want and rewrite the imports, which of course break other users of that code, but so would your hypothetical `go get` example which would require different imports.

Answer (score 3):

You've already answered the question yourself, so I'm just confirming that it is how you would do it.

In your example, you would use: `go get -u github.com/foo/bar/src/main/go`

Sure, it doesn't look pretty, but keep in mind that most of the yuckiness comes from paths in your control.

For example, it could be: `go get -u github.com/foo/bar/go`

I can confirm this works since this is what we use in production.

By design, the go get path is where you would get it from. You do have another option - to use redirection (like [gopkg.in](https://labix.org/gopkg.in)). However, that comes with its own added complexity.